# Problem with Timepicker antd 5.0.4 - Can't resolve 'antd/lib/time-picker/style/index.js'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, antd

Hello i've got a problem with antd Timepicker component:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'antd/lib/time-picker/style/index.js'
```

I changed webpack config according to migration docs
https://ant.design/docs/react/migration-v5

```
const { convertLegacyToken } = require("@ant-design/compatible/lib");

const { defaultAlgorithm, defaultSeed } = theme;

const mapToken = defaultAlgorithm(defaultSeed);
const v4Token = convertLegacyToken(mapToken);
```

module webpack config:

```
     module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(jsx|tsx|js|ts)$/,
                loader: "ts-loader",
                options: {
                    transpileOnly: true,
                    getCustomTransformers: () => ({
                        before: [
                            tsImportPluginFactory({
                                libraryName: "antd",
                                libraryDirectory: "lib",
                                style: true,
                            }),
                        ],
                    }),
                },
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "less-loader",
                        options: {
                            lessOptions: {
                                modifyVars: v4Token,
                                javascriptEnabled: true,
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
            },
        ],
    },
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the answer, all I had to do was to delete  `style: true` from ts-loader

So right now it looks like this

```
  {
                test: /\.(jsx|tsx|js|ts)$/,
                loader: "ts-loader",
                options: {
                    transpileOnly: true,
                    getCustomTransformers: () => ({
                        before: [
                            tsImportPluginFactory({
                                libraryName: "antd",
                                libraryDirectory: "lib",
                            }),
                        ],
                    }),
                },
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
```